# Unit test on embedded Mono script in C++ code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mono

I've embedded Mono in my C++ application (C# as scripting language) and so far so good, but now I need to make unit tests on C# code with NUnit and completly don't know how to start. Here's the problem in pseudocode:

C++ code:

```
#include <SomeCppOnlyLib.h>

int main() {
    SomeMUSTBEInitializations();
    EmbeddAndInvokeMonoScriptDLL();
}

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int GetMagicNumber() {
        return SomeCppOnlyLib::GetMagicNumber();
    }
}
```

C# code (MonoScript.DLL):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class MonoScript
{
    [DllImport ("__Internal")]
    extern static int GetMagicNumber();
    public int GetBetterMagicNumber() {
        return GetMagicNumber()+10000;
    }
}
```

So here is the question:

How can I do an unit test on **GetBetterMagicNumber()**?

I am using MonoDevelop to create managed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to test the c# code independently. Put a wrapper in the interopfile if necessary, and test the actual function directly using nunit.